# Beginner to python or programming as a whole, getting this error and unable to solve it

Tags: python, error-handling, syntax-error, exec, eval

Here is the code:

```py
p1, p2 = eval(input("input the share price of two organizations:   "))
if (p1>p2):
    print("the first organization is performing better")
```

here is the error:

```
TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object
```

Comment: **Do not use `eval()` with input from user**. Is a serious security issue. They could just input any piece of code.

Comment: what should i use instead?

Comment: `p1 = int(input("input the share price of two organizations:   "))`

Comment: Besides, you don't need to evaluate anything there. Do you know [what `eval` does](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#eval)? If you wnat python to read the input (a string) as a number, just use `int()` or `float()`

Comment: If you want to deal with a string containing two values, you may want to [split it](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+split+string). And then you have a very interesting exercise extracting each number from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's `eval()` allows you to evaluate arbitrary Python expressions from a string-based or compiled-code-based input. However, as the comments correctly say, this is best avoided.

All you need to do from here is convert `strings` to `integers`.

This would work better:

```py
# get the inputs:    p1, p2
b = input("input the share price of two organizations:  ")

b = b.split(sep=',') # split the list into 2

# strip the white spaces
p1= b[0].strip()
p2= b[1].strip()

# convert to integers
p1, p2 = int(p1), int(p2)

# do some logic
if (p1>p2):
    print("the first organization is performing better")
```